# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is working across different domains. Why?

Tags: security, cors, http-headers

I have an issue where the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set, but still the browser allows requests from a different domain.

For example, let's say it is these two domains. They both serve the same web page from the same server, because the service is white labelled.

- subdomain.my-domain.com
- subdomain.other-domain.com

The server responds with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://subdomain.my-domain.com` when browsing the site on `https://subdomain.other-domain.com`. In my mind, the browser should reject the requests, because the origins are different, but it doesn't. Why does it allow this? Is it because they both resolve to the same `*.my-domain.com` certificate?

When I tested in development, the browser would reject requests from `localhost:3000` if the header had the value of `localhost:3001`. Here the port is different, but according the MDN, it should also work when the domain is different.

> Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port of the URL used to access it.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin

Please let me know if I can supply any other useful information, there isn't too much code to show here.

EDIT: I believe I misunderstood how this header worked. I thought it would only allow requests from origins matching the header value, but it will always allow the current origin, and then that header opens up the door for additional other origins. I will answer my own question when I can. Please correct my if I am incorrect.

Comment: Browsers let so-called "simple" CORS requests through. The presence or absence of any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response to such a request only dictates whether the browser will allow the client to read the response. Preflight only occurs for non-simple requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests.